# phpfmt php formatting extension eror: phpfmt: php_bin "php" is invalid

Tags: php, macos, visual-studio-code

Recently I updated my VS code on my macOS. I'm now running vs code version **1.41.1.**

Ever since the reinstall, the [phpfmt extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt) is no longer working and giving me the

> phpfmt: php_bin "php" is invalid`

pop up every time I save a file.

I tried removing VS code and installing it again. I removed the extension and reinstalled it as well yet I am still getting this error.

Is there any other settings i can clear. I can't find this error anywhere online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you have PHP installed:

**Edit your vscode settings (JSON view) add this option:**

> `"phpfmt.php_bin": "php"`

**If you want auto formatting on save:**

All Languages:

> `"editor.formatOnSave": true`

Just PHP:

> `"[php]": { "editor.formatOnSave": true }`

you can always check out the plugin page too:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt

has this bits of info on this + further configuration

happy coding!

Answer (score 7):

Just add below code in `setting.json` in `VS Code`

```json
"phpfmt.php_bin": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"
```

in my case the location is in `xampp` so just add your `php.exe` location.

Comment: the user is on macOS

Answer (score 5):

On **Mac Os**:

In the vscode settings (**JSON** view) extend the ^^ above option with the **Mac Os PHP path**:

```
 "phpfmt.php_bin": "/usr/bin/php"
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks very much. Did b.t.w. not work for me in a "[php]" subsection (or however to name it), but below settings.json "root". And pointing to "/usr/local/bin/php" which actually points to a brew Cellar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find dir to file php.exe and then you can fig that easily by this way below:
"phpfmt.php_bin": "F:/Xampp/php/php.exe",

F:/Xampp/php/php.exe  - my directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
"phpfmt.php_bin": "C:/xampp/php/php.exe"
```

- open setting.json in VS code
- You have to find your php.exe path and paste it after "phpfmt.php_bin": "**php.exe path**"